# Generic method uses type as argument

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method which I cannot figure out how to compile

```
private ConditionalCheckRetryHandler<T> T getConditionalCheckRetryHandler() {
    return new ConditionalCheckRetryHandler<T>;
}
```

Ideally I would like to call `<ClassName>getConditionalCheckRetryHandler()` and return a class of that type but `T` doesn't seem to exist. Is there any way to do this sensibly?

Comment: Your code does not compile and your question does not compute.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not compile.

If you have class

```
class ConditionalCheckRetryHandler<T>{
   //...   
}
```

then you can use following method

```
private <T> ConditionalCheckRetryHandler<T>  getConditionalCheckRetryHandler() {
        return new ConditionalCheckRetryHandler<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we do it with a [runtime type token](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html):

```
private ConditionalCheckRetryHandler<T> T getConditionalCheckRetryHandler(Class<T> returnType) {
    return new ConditionalCheckRetryHandler<T>();
}
```

So you can call it like this: `getConditionalCheckRetryHandler(DesiredType.class)`.

Comment: This binds the `T` to whatever the caller specifies.
In this case [Dimitrys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7330729/dmitry-gorkovets) solution is more elegant because we don't *need* to bind to that type.